# What return type should I define for a function that returns a class?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have a function that returns a class like this:

```
function createClass() {
  return class implements ISomeInterface {/* ... */}
}

export { createClass }
```

But now ESLint complains with the following warning:

```
Missing return type on function.
```

and links to this [ESLint rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.8.2/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md).

How would I define the return type of `createClass` to make ESLint happy?

Comment: Your function returns `typeof (Anonymous class)` so how are you going to indicate `anonymous`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following interface corresponding to the anonymous class's instance type,

```
interface ISomeInterface {
  prop: string;
  method(): void;
}
```

it is also helpful for you to define an interface corresponding to the class's *constructor*.  This would include any static properties of the constructor, as well as the class's [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures), like this:

```
interface SomeInterfaceConstructor {
  new(prop: string): ISomeInterface;
}
```

That `new(prop: string): ISomeInterface` means if you have a value `c` of type `SomeInterfaceConstructor`, then you can call `new c("foobar");` and get an `ISomeInterface` out.  (Note that it does *not* mean that `SomeInterfaceConstructor` has a *method* named `"new"`, even though the syntax looks like that).

Armed with a name for the constructor's interface, you can simply have `createClass()` return that type:

```
function createClass(): SomeInterfaceConstructor {
  return class implements ISomeInterface {
    constructor(public prop: string) { }
    method() {
      console.log("My prop is " + this.prop);
    }
  }
}
```

And you can see that it works:

```
const c = createClass();
// const c: SomeInterfaceConstructor;
const i = new c("foobar");
// const i: ISomeInterface
i.method(); // My prop is foobar
export { createClass }
```

And when you export `createClass()`, you might want to export the `SomeInterfaceConstructor` type, as well as `ISomeInterface` if it's not already exported (or defined elsewhere).

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGUIBbYfFNLXOAbwCg44woIwAuOAZximQHMA3IzhkYACwgATABQBKTgDcICKcIC+9eqEixElDDjzEyFVIdwBhCEh5QArthjQ6IpMADuMlm052BCgQm5AbUwBpaOtDw6PZITgg2cNhQwJiolgA2mFxc8pzBZlRG1ra8js5QrkypMPZQSMnZuYgkYJnAZChcQaQh5mHVTMk2dhXQ3vYARpkI2MysHNy8AXRwmsOiwBLS8kOb2KMQHQB0mRD8MgBEALIAngtsiD1XcADUcBIIXCc+YHLCTYbdb0TT0Q5lZJwAC8yVS6WAWRyeQB9AA9GiRpDsAU+kULIjRuUnNBhBCeIgYXB3B5ktd0BAIFNMFArqiMViKQhOEQ8aEjPQECcxJJZAC4Bz7o8wM84AymSytEA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. You mentioned anonymous class; would there be a different way of doing this if the class had a name? If it were instead written like this: `class SomeClass implements ISomeInterface {}; return SomeClass;`

Comment: It wouldn't really help you either; the problem isn't that the class is anonymous but that the scope of any name you give it is confined to the function's implementation and is not exposed to the callers... there's no externally visible `SomeClass` for you to annotate the return type as `typeof SomeClass`.  If you refactored your code so that the class declaration itself is visible outside the function, you could write `typeof SomeClass` to get a type for it without having to re-describe it yourself.  But that's probably a non-starter for you, see [this](https://tsplay.dev/nmqbRW)